# Private user dataroom package

Tags: django, django-forms, package

Does anybody know a good django package or tool to provide a private "user dataroom" where every user can upload a few documents which could be accessed and managed by an admin trought an admin interface?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/file-managers/

This is a great site for finding good django apps, here is a list of FileManagers.

I would go with one that has:

Documentation, an active Github and has PyPi

These are usually good indicators that it is active and people are using and collaborating on it.

Good Luck!